# How to load a class inside the function in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I have a class already load inside `__construct()` of my page, after that once again I want to load this class, inside another function. Here is my code.

```
<?php

class MainClass {
  public $config;

  public function __construct($config) {
    $this->config = $config;
  }

  public function routes() {
    // here I need to load the config class
  }
}
?>
```

inside routes function i want to call an array form config class file

Comment: I added a missing `}` at the end of your class definition; please double-check that your original source code isn't also missing a closing `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$config` is already loaded as a property of the object, since you passed it in the constructor.  If you need to access the `$config` from another member function, just use `$this->config->whatever`

```
public function routes() {
  //here i need to load the config class
  $something = $this->config->somearray[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function routes() {
    require_once "/path/to/YourClass.php"
    $your_class_instance = new YourClass();
}
```